# Prove that in a $32$ team games, there must exist $2$ teams with same number of wins,losses and ties.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Suppose that we have $32$ teams in a tournament, we divide them into $8$ groups, where each group has $4$ teams, in each group, every team will play two games with the rest $3$ teams and each game can be win/loss/tie, now I want to prove that there must exist two teams having same number of wins,losses and ties.

Comment: If you want to prove it, then go ahead! No one's stopping you!

Comment: Have you read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) before? This is really good advice for writing better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose for a particular team, there are $a$ wins, $b$ losses and $c$ ties, then we have $a+b+c=6$ (Why?).

Count the number of solutions to the above equation and compare them to the number of teams we have. This is what is known as [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).